# OR Tools - VRP - Handling cases where no optimal solution can be found

Tags: c#, or-tools

I am building a solver for a Vehicle Routing Problem based on Googles ORTools.

For simple problems, or high capacity problems, it works fine, however for most "real" data sets I end up with solutions that either run indefinitely or time out.

Afer some thought I realise not all real world problems can be solved, or optimal.  E.g. I may want most vehicles to do no more than 500km a day.  However if I have to deliver to someone 600Km away the entire solution will fail.

How can I deal with these scenarios? Right now it seems to be a binary pass or fail.  I am more than happy for certain cases to be ignored or for it to return a suboptimal solution.

Here is the code for my solution

```
public List<OptimisedVehicleRoute> Start(Location depot, List<Location> locations, int numVehicles = 1, float maxDistanceKmPerVehicle = 1000f, float maxDistanceKmSlack = 5f)
{
    // Create Routing Index Manager
    var depotIndex = locations.IndexOf(depot);
    var manager = new RoutingIndexManager(locations.Count, numVehicles, depotIndex);
    Console.WriteLine($"Depot at {depot.Postcode}");

    var routing = new RoutingModel(manager);

    var numCalls = 0l;

    int transitCallbackIndex = routing.RegisterTransitCallback((long fromIndex, long toIndex) =>
    {
        numCalls++;

        // Convert from routing variable Index to distance matrix NodeIndex.
        var fromNode = manager.IndexToNode(fromIndex);
        var toNode = manager.IndexToNode(toIndex);

        var fromLocation = locations[fromNode];
        var toLocation = locations[toNode];

        var mDistance = fromLocation.DistanceTo(toLocation);

        return mDistance;
    });

    // The arc cost evaluator tells the solver how to calculate the cost of travel between any two locations
    routing.SetArcCostEvaluatorOfAllVehicles(transitCallbackIndex);

    long maxVehicleDistanceSlack = (long)Math.Round(maxDistanceKmSlack * 1000); // slack per day
    long maxVehicleDistance = (long)Math.Round(maxDistanceKmPerVehicle * 1000); // 1000km max distance per day

    routing.AddDimension(transitCallbackIndex, maxVehicleDistanceSlack, maxVehicleDistance, true, "Distance");
    RoutingDimension distanceDimension = routing.GetMutableDimension("Distance");
    distanceDimension.SetGlobalSpanCostCoefficient(100);

    var searchParameters = operations_research_constraint_solver.DefaultRoutingSearchParameters();
    searchParameters.FirstSolutionStrategy = FirstSolutionStrategy.Types.Value.PathCheapestArc;

    var timer = new Stopwatch();
    timer.Start();
    searchParameters.LogSearch = true;
    var solution = routing.SolveWithParameters(searchParameters);
    timer.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine(timer.Elapsed.TotalSeconds);

    var optimisedVehicleRoutes = this.CreateOptimisedVehicleLocations(locations, numVehicles, routing, manager, solution);

    this.OptimisedDistanceKm = optimisedVehicleRoutes.Sum(r => r.TotalDistanceKm);

    routing.Dispose();

    return optimisedVehicleRoutes;
}
```

P.s. if anyone can help me understand what "Slack" is actually used for I'd appreciate it.  I initially assumed it was tolerance per vehicle (i.e. a slack of 10km allows that vehicle to go 10km over its max route distance). But now I am unsure

Comment: Slack is for the driver so the drive doesn't violate traffic rules and driver more hours than allowed or  to factor in weather conditions.

Comment: Thanks! So how would you use that? I presume then I am using Slack wrongly here then? How do you account for tolerances?

Comment: What are tolerances in this case?  The tolerances are to make sure drivers reach destination without violating any rules or regulations.

Comment: Slack is how much longer/shorter a shipment may take do to factors like : Weather, Truck Break Down, Previous stops taking long to load/unload.

Comment: Usually, the model has two dimensions, one for distance and one for time. Along the path, each node is associated with a cumul variable. The formula is `cumul(next(I)) = cumul(I) + transit(I, next(I)) + slack(I)`. For distance, slack is most likely always 0. For time, it can be non zero and then it corresponds to waiting time before the node.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you have a location at 600km with a maximum allowed distance to 500km you problem is basically unfeasible...

BUT you can allow the solver to drop this location using `AddDisjunction()` making your problem feasible...

please take a look at our example on the documentation site: https://developers.google.com/optimization/routing/penalties

Comment: Thank you, this worked very well.  Do you have any guidance on how to derive the penalty figure?